# Why is adding a navigation controller making my array disappear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

Currently I have a `UIViewController` with a couple of buttons that when pressed move to a `UITableViewController`. Each button loads a specific array of data to the `UITableViewController` by identifying the segue of the specific button and displaying the corresponding data.
This works fine as is.

However I wish to add an embedded `UINavigationController` so I can navigate through the `UITableViewController` and and corresponding views while still being able to 'press back' to the initial `UIViewController`.

Firstly, where am I meant to put this. I tried over the tableViewController and 2 things happen -

**a)** If the segues still go to the `UITableViewController`, there is no navigation displayed.

**b)** If I move the segues to go to the `UINavigationController`, none of my arrays show in the tableViewController, but I do have navigation.

Where do I link my segues or where do I embed the `UINavigationController` so this works?
(I haven't put any code as I don't think this will involve it, but if it does just let me know and I will add).

Not sure if I'm missing something but, it's not working. I want to be able to still utilize the buttons I already have and not use the buttons on the navigation from the UIViewController to the UITableViewController.

**For Hiding the Navigation on root**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding fully, but I would still like to be able to press the buttons on my UIViewController to initially get to the UITableViewController without having to navigate in the NavBar. I think what you guys are saying will allow me to navigate to the UITableViewController through the NavBar on the UIViewController. As I already have a banner on this controller, can I still do this by utilizing the buttons I already have. Or am I missing something really straightforward here... as when I the root as the controller with the buttons, the navigation disappears on the tableview.

Comment: Turns out I forgot to change my segues with the arrays from modal to push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewController which has 2 buttons can be made as rootViewController to the NavigationController. The NavigationController can be added to the window.

Window -> NavigationController -> UIViewController (as rootView)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Select the root view controller->editor->embed in->navigation controller

Comment: You'll also need to change the segues to push segues.

Comment: That got it working! Is there anyway I can hide the navbar on the root viewcontroller, as I have a banner and I don't really need the navigation on there.

Comment: It's all good. I worked it out and it seems to be working fine with this on my rootview.